# Why is this regular expression not excluding the line when there are numbers at the end of a line in this string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to scan documents and identify where sections of the document begin and end.  Sometimes, the document has a table of contents that lists page numbers I do not want to capture the TOC because it does not identify part of the document.  I have been messing with this for sometime and am stuck on something.  I can't seem to avoid capturing the lines from the table of contents with line numbers

Here is the regular expression

```
verbose_item_pattern_3 = re.compile(r"""
  ^            # begin match at newline
  \t*          # 0-or-more tabspace
  [ ]*         # 0-or-more blank space
  I            # a capital I
  [tT][eE][mM] # one character from each of the three sets this allows for unknown case
  \t*          # 0-or-more tabspace
  [ ]*         # 0-or-more blankspace
  \d{1,2}      # 1-or-2 digits
  [.]?         # 0-or-1 literal .
  \(?          # 0-or-1 literal open paren
  [a-e]?       # 0-or-1 letter in the range a-e
  \)?          # 0-or-1 closing paren
  .*           # any number of unknown characters so we can have words and punctuation
  [^0-9]       # anything but [0-9]
  $           # 1 newline character
  """, re.VERBOSE|re.MULTILINE)
```

here is an example of a line I DO NOT want to capture

```
test_string='\nItem 6.       TITLE ITEM 6..................................................25\n'
```

Here is an example of what I do want to capture

```
test_string='\nItem 6.       TITLE ITEM 6 maybe other words here who knows  \n'
```

But when I run

```
re.findall(verbose_item_pattern_3,test_string)
```

the result is

```
['Item 6.       TITLE ITEM 6..................................................25\n']
```

Now the thing to me that is interesting is that if my test string is this

```
test_string='PART I\nItem 1.       TITLE ITEM 1...................................................1\nItem 2.       TITLE ITEM 2..................................................21\n'
```

and run that with
    re.findall(verbose_item_pattern_3,test_string)

the result is closer to what I want but still not correct

```
['Item 2.       TITLE ITEM 2..................................................21\n']
```

There should not be anything captured

Comment: Note how the newline is captured..

Comment: Could you explain why your example should not be captured?  What shouldn't be matching?

Comment: I can't seem to understand what the desired output should be. It would be much more helpful to see a more inclusive snippet of source input, show what it is doing wrong, and showing what it should be doing instead.

Comment: I am trying to not capture any line that ends with a number Hpefully I clarified it above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex matches because of three things.

1. most of it is optional, so it is very unspecific
2. there is a `.*` that eats the entire line, so your last condition `[^0-9]` will never come to bear, and that's because:
3. the newline character itself *fulfills* `[^0-9]`, so the `[^0-9]` can successfully match even though the line ends in a number.

The minimal change would be to use a negative look-behind at the end:

```
verbose_item_pattern_3 = re.compile(r"""
  ^            # start-of-line
  \t*          # 0-or-more tabspace
  [ ]*         # 0-or-more blank space
  I            # a capital I
  [tT][eE][mM] # one character from each of the three sets this allows for unknown case
  \t*          # 0-or-more tabspace
  [ ]*         # 0-or-more blankspace
  \d{1,2}      # 1-or-2 digits
  [.]?         # 0-or-1 literal .
  \(?          # 0-or-1 literal open paren
  [a-e]?       # 0-or-1 letter in the range a-e
  \)?          # 0-or-1 closing paren
  .*           # any number of unknown characters so we can have words and punctuation
  $            # end-of-line
  (?<![0-9])   # NOT preceded by a decimal digit (via look-behind)
  """, re.VERBOSE|re.MULTILINE)
```

Note that neither the `^` not the `$` actually match a newline character. They match *the position right after* (`^`) or *the position right before* (`$`) a newline character. The newline character itself is never part of the match.

I've changed their comments to the more precise `start-of-line` and `end-of-line` for that reason.

Also note how I can apply a negative look-behind even after the `$`. Doing it this way is useful to prevent backtracking, making the regex faster.

Comment: thanks so much I was trying to get my head around negative look-behind and this example makes it very clear.  Both answers were very helpful you got accepted because you were first thanks

Comment: Sorry I changed the title to make it easier for the next lost soul find the right answer and that caused your answer to get unmarked I just realized that and marked it again I did not know that was how SO worked

Comment: @PyNew Not to worry, oll is well!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you expect your example strings to not match because the last character in the line is a digit, and your regex ends with `[^0-9]$`.

The reason this is behaving incorrectly is that `$` will match just before a `\n`, but also at the very end of the string.  What ends up happening here is that the `.*` matches the digits, then `[^0-9]` matches the `\n`, and `$` matches at the end of the string.  Consider the following example which uses capturing groups to show how this works:

```
>>> re.match(r'(.*)([^0-9])$', '...12\n').groups()
('...12', '\n')
```

To fix this, you can prevent `[^0-9]` from matching line break characters by changing it to `[^0-9\n]`:

```
verbose_item_pattern_3 = re.compile(r"""
  ^            # begin match at newline
  \t*          # 0-or-more tabspace
  [ ]*         # 0-or-more blank space
  I            # a capital I
  [tT][eE][mM] # one character from each of the three sets this allows for unknown case
  \t*          # 0-or-more tabspace
  [ ]*         # 0-or-more blankspace
  \d{1,2}      # 1-or-2 digits
  [.]?         # 0-or-1 literal .
  \(?          # 0-or-1 literal open paren
  [a-e]?       # 0-or-1 letter in the range a-e
  \)?          # 0-or-1 closing paren
  .*           # any number of unknown characters so we can have words and punctuation
  [^0-9\n]     # anything but [0-9] and line breaks
  $           # 1 newline character
  """, re.VERBOSE|re.MULTILINE)
```

Examples (using above regex):

```
>>> verbose_item_pattern_3.findall('\nItem 6.       TITLE ITEM 6.....25\n')
[]
>>> verbose_item_pattern_3.findall('\nItem 6.       TITLE ITEM 6.....\n')
['Item 6.       TITLE ITEM 6.....']
```

Comment: +1 That's an even more minimal change than my version. Strange that I did not think of that.

Comment: @FJ Thanks a lot this was very helpful and helps me better understand how to work with regular expressions.  The only reason you did not get the accepted answer is because I think Tomalak beat you by seconds and his answer also helped me better understand what I was doing wrong